# Creating a FriendlyId with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, methods, friendly-id

I have a `User` model that has a `has_many` relationship with a `Post` model.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :user_id

  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'd like to setup the url of my post model where the name of the post's owner goes first followed by the name of the post:

```
localhost:3000/john/sample-post
```

I tried setting this up in my `slug_candidates` method inside my post model but got errors:

```
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, user: [:slugged, :history]

  def slug_candidates
    [:name, [self.user.name, :name]]
  end
end
```

What would I need to change in this method to get it to work?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the `Post` slug. You can set this up in your `routes`. What are your current `routes`?

Comment: I'm using the restful resources that come out of the box via scaffold. So: `resources :users, posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers) explain this with the following example:

> You can prefix routes with a named parameter also:
>
> ```
> scope ':username' do
>   resources :posts
> end
> ```
>
> This will provide you with URLs such as /bob/posts/1 and will allow you to reference the username part of the path as `params[:username]` in controllers, helpers and views.